# Why is my overloaded multiplication operator not recognized?

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, c++14, c++17

Why does the following code yield the compiler error *no match for `operator*`*?

```
template<class E>
class vector_expression {};

template<class Tuple>
class vector
    : public vector_expression<vector<Tuple>>
{
public:
    using value_type = typename Tuple::value_type;
};

namespace detail
{
    template<typename T>
    class scalar
        : public vector_expression<scalar<T>>
    {};
}

template<class E1, class E2, class BinaryOperation>
class vector_binary_operation
    : public vector_expression<vector_binary_operation<E1, E2, BinaryOperation>>
{
public:
    template<class F1, class F2>
    vector_binary_operation(F1&& e1, F2&& e2, BinaryOperation op)
        : m_e1(std::forward<F1>(e1)), m_e2(std::forward<F2>(e2)),
          m_op(std::move(op))
    { }

private:
    E1 m_e1;
    E2 m_e2;
    BinaryOperation m_op;
};

template<class E>
vector_binary_operation<detail::scalar<typename E::value_type>, E, std::multiplies<>> operator*(typename E::value_type value, E&& e) {
    return { std::move(value), std::forward<E>(e), std::multiplies<>{} };
}
template<class E>
vector_binary_operation<E, detail::scalar<typename E::value_type>, std::multiplies<>> operator*(E&& e, typename E::value_type value) {
    return { std::forward<E>(e), std::move(value), std::multiplies<>{} };
}

int main()
{
    vector<std::array<double, 3>> x;
    3 * x;

    return 0;
}
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a3a156762171e43b)

Comment: Your "DEMO" link doesn't work for me.

Comment: FYI, `3` is an `int`, not a `double`. Templates are sensitive to stuff like that.

Comment: @MartinBonner Sorry, fixed that.

Comment: @Cornstalks That's not the point. It still doesn't work if you replace `3` by `3.`.

Comment: I think I just need to use `typename std::decay_t<E>::value_type` instead of `typename E::value_type`.

Comment: @Cornstalks: That was my first guess - but nope :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two overloaded `operator*` that are (ignoring the return type for the moment):

```
template <class E>
R operator*(typename E::value_type, E&& );

template <class E>
R operator*(E&&, typename E::value_type );
```

In both cases, one argument is a non-deduced context. Let's start with the 2nd overload. When we call with `3 * x`, `E` is deduced as `int`, there is no `int::value_type`, so that's a substitution failure.

In the first overload, we deduce `E` as `vector<std::array<double, 3>>&`. Note that it's a *reference*. As such, there is no `E::value_type` because it's a reference type. You have to first remove that part (for both overloads). The simplest way is to introduce a second defaulted template argument that is an *un*referenced version of `E`:

```
template<class E, class ER = std::remove_reference_t<E>>
vector_binary_operation<detail::scalar<typename ER::value_type>, ER, std::multiplies<>>
operator*(typename ER::value_type value, E&& e);
```

With that fix, now your code doesn't compile for a difference reason: `scalar` not having a constructor. But that's an unrelated problem.

Comment: `decay` is shorter to type (and the additional transformations it performs is harmless)

Comment: You're right, I've just noticed that I'd forgotten to write `std::decay_t<E>` instead of `E`.

Comment: @T.C. It's shorter, but I just sometimes prefer `remove_reference` for the clarity that we're actually just removing a reference.

Answer (score 1):

The code fails because `x` is an lvalue-reference on which you can't apply the `::` access operator. In order to do so, you should `std::decay_t` the deduced type `E` first, i.e. write

```
typename std::decay_t<E>::value_type
```